# Python Pandas count function on condition and subset

Tags: python, pandas, counter

i have a dataframe like this

```
F_Class  Product    Packages
Apple    Apple_A          1           
Apple    Apple_A          2           
Apple    Apple_A          1           
Apple    Apple_B          2           
Bananas  Banana_A      n.a.           
Bananas  Banana_A      n.a.
```

I want to build the following count function to count the items in my dataframe like shown below.

- The Function should count by the Subset `['F_Class','Product']`
- If `df['Packages'] == 2` then increase by `+2` else increase by `+1`

The result should look like this:

```
F_Class  Product    Packages    Counter
Apple    Apple_A          1           1
Apple    Apple_A          2           3
Apple    Apple_A          1           4
Apple    Apple_B          2           2
Bananas  Banana_A      n.a.           1
Bananas  Banana_A      n.a.           2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need sum by `Packages` numbers use [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) with replace missing values to `1`:

```
df['Packages'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Packages'], errors='coerce')

df['Counter'] = (df.assign(Packages = df['Packages'].fillna(1).astype(int))
                   .groupby(['F_Class','Product'])['Packages'].cumsum())
print (df)
   F_Class   Product  Packages  Counter
0    Apple   Apple_A       1.0        1
1    Apple   Apple_A       2.0        3
2    Apple   Apple_A       1.0        4
3    Apple   Apple_B       2.0        2
4  Bananas  Banana_A       NaN        1
5  Bananas  Banana_A       NaN        2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.assign(Packages = df['Packages'].fillna(1).astype(int)))
   F_Class   Product  Packages
0    Apple   Apple_A         1
1    Apple   Apple_A         2
2    Apple   Apple_A         1
3    Apple   Apple_B         2
4  Bananas  Banana_A         1
5  Bananas  Banana_A         1
```

Comment: Worked Fine Thx !

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) together with [`df.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) as follows:

```
df['Counter'] = (df.groupby(['F_Class','Product'])['Packages']
                   .transform(lambda x: x.eq('2').add(1).cumsum()))


print(df)

   F_Class   Product Packages  Counter
0    Apple   Apple_A        1        1
1    Apple   Apple_A        2        3
2    Apple   Apple_A        1        4
3    Apple   Apple_B        2        2
4  Bananas  Banana_A     n.a.        1
5  Bananas  Banana_A     n.a.        2
```

If your values in column `Packages` are integer rather than string, modify `'2'` to `2`:

```
df['Counter'] = (df.groupby(['F_Class','Product'])['Packages']
                   .transform(lambda x: x.eq(2).add(1).cumsum()))
```

Comment: Thank you, thats what I am thinking,too.